# flex compiler error (warning) message in flex ant task

Tags: java, linux, apache-flex, ant

I have following warnings if I compile our flex project with the ant task from the flex sdk. Does anyone have an idea where this comes from and why this happens and if I can safely ignore it? (The swf file itself seems to get created without an actual error)

```
[mxmlc] The args attribute is deprecated. Please use nested arg elements.
[mxmlc] Loading configuration file /home/jrose/SDKs/flex_sdk_3-1/frameworks/flex-config.xml
[mxmlc] Locking assertion failure.  Backtrace:
[mxmlc] #0 /usr/lib/libxcb-xlib.so.0 [0x786057c7]
[mxmlc] #1 /usr/lib/libxcb-xlib.so.0(xcb_xlib_unlock+0x31) [0x78605891]
[mxmlc] #2 /usr/lib/libX11.so.6(_XReply+0x254) [0x77053494]
[mxmlc] #3 /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-sun-1.5.0.16/jre/lib/i386/xawt/libmawt.so [0x77e6ddce]
[mxmlc] #4 /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-sun-1.5.0.16/jre/lib/i386/xawt/libmawt.so [0x77e57d77]
[mxmlc] #5 /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-sun-1.5.0.16/jre/lib/i386/xawt/libmawt.so [0x77e57ef3]
[mxmlc] #6 /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-sun-1.5.0.16/jre/lib/i386/xawt/libmawt.so(Java_sun_awt_X11GraphicsEnvironment_initDisplay+0x26) [0x77e58136]
[mxmlc] #7 [0xb1411008]
[mxmlc] #8 [0xb140ab6b]
[mxmlc] #9 [0xb140ab6b]
[mxmlc] #10 [0xb1408236]
[mxmlc] #11 /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-sun-1.5.0.16/jre/lib/i386/server/libjvm.so [0xb76a3eec]
[mxmlc] #12 /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-sun-1.5.0.16/jre/lib/i386/server/libjvm.so [0xb7873ae8]
[mxmlc] #13 /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-sun-1.5.0.16/jre/lib/i386/server/libjvm.so [0xb76a3d1f]
[mxmlc] #14 /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-sun-1.5.0.16/jre/lib/i386/server/libjvm.so(JVM_DoPrivileged+0x32d) [0xb770182d]
[mxmlc] #15 /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-sun-1.5.0.16/jre/lib/i386/libjava.so(Java_java_security_AccessController_doPrivileged__Ljava_security_PrivilegedAction_2+0x3d) [0xb73a730d]
[mxmlc] #16 [0xb1410898]
[mxmlc] #17 [0xb140aa94]
[mxmlc] #18 [0xb1408236]
[mxmlc] #19 /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-sun-1.5.0.16/jre/lib/i386/server/libjvm.so [0xb76a3eec]
[mxmlc] Locking assertion failure.  Backtrace:
[mxmlc] #0 /usr/lib/libxcb-xlib.so.0 [0x786057c7]
[mxmlc] #1 /usr/lib/libxcb-xlib.so.0(xcb_xlib_lock+0x2e) [0x7860596e]
[mxmlc] #2 /usr/lib/libX11.so.6 [0x77052619]
[mxmlc] #3 /usr/lib/libX11.so.6(XGetVisualInfo+0x26) [0x77048666]
[mxmlc] #4 /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-sun-1.5.0.16/jre/lib/i386/xawt/libmawt.so [0x77e570b9]
[mxmlc] #5 /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-sun-1.5.0.16/jre/lib/i386/xawt/libmawt.so [0x77e57303]
[mxmlc] #6 /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-sun-1.5.0.16/jre/lib/i386/xawt/libmawt.so [0x77e57fa1]
[mxmlc] #7 /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-sun-1.5.0.16/jre/lib/i386/xawt/libmawt.so(Java_sun_awt_X11GraphicsEnvironment_initDisplay+0x26) [0x77e58136]
[mxmlc] #8 [0xb1411008]
[mxmlc] #9 [0xb140ab6b]
[mxmlc] #10 [0xb140ab6b]
[mxmlc] #11 [0xb1408236]
[mxmlc] #12 /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-sun-1.5.0.16/jre/lib/i386/server/libjvm.so [0xb76a3eec]
[mxmlc] #13 /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-sun-1.5.0.16/jre/lib/i386/server/libjvm.so [0xb7873ae8]
[mxmlc] #14 /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-sun-1.5.0.16/jre/lib/i386/server/libjvm.so [0xb76a3d1f]
[mxmlc] #15 /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-sun-1.5.0.16/jre/lib/i386/server/libjvm.so(JVM_DoPrivileged+0x32d) [0xb770182d]
[mxmlc] #16 /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-sun-1.5.0.16/jre/lib/i386/libjava.so(Java_java_security_AccessController_doPrivileged__Ljava_security_PrivilegedAction_2+0x3d) [0xb73a730d]
[mxmlc] #17 [0xb1410898]
[mxmlc] #18 [0xb140aa94]
[mxmlc] #19 [0xb1408236]
```

**Ant target**

```
<target name="compile-flex-swf" description="creates swf file">
    <mxmlc file="${basedir}/flex_src/company_gui.mxml" 
        keep-generated-actionscript="false" 
        output="${basedir}/target/${ant.project.name}.swf" 
        fork="true" 
        debug="${flex.debug}" 
        services="${basedir}/WebContent/WEB-INF/flex/services-config.xml" 
        actionscript-file-encoding="UTF-8" 
        optimize="true">

        <load-config filename="${FLEX_HOME}/frameworks/flex-config.xml" />
        <context-root>company</context-root>
        <compiler.library-path dir="${LCDS_HOME}/resources/frameworks" append="true">
            <include name="libs/fds.swc" />
        </compiler.library-path>
        <compiler.library-path dir="../company_flex/target" append="true">
            <include name="*.swc" />
        </compiler.library-path>
    </mxmlc>
</target>
```

Comment: Can you paste the code from your build.xml file here?

Comment: I added the target definition from my ant file, its pretty standard, and as I said, the compilation itself doesn't fail, it just spits out theese warnings and I really want to know where they come from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those backtraces really have nothing to do with flex or ant. It really is just an interaction between AWT and XCB. You can find more information with the [sun bug 6532373](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6532373) or the [Xlib bug 11390](https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=11390).
There are workarounds, but I don't think they are necessary (other than removing those nasty messages).

Comment: I think thats it. I actually found the same errors in another build recently.